# screen sharing turns on remote monitor

Tags: screen-sharing

When I connect to my work computer with screen sharing, the work computer's screen turns on and shows what im doing. I lock the work machine and turn off its display.

Is there a way to prevent the remote screen from turning on during screen sharing.

Comment: check this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/59322/4680